# How to lock focus for flash photo capture on iPhone 10, is there an api bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, ios-camera

I'm having issues locking the focus point and taking a photo with flash on iPhone X (iOS 12.0) using the AVFoundation kit. How do I lock focus correctly on iOS 10 and up?

I need to take a photo with flash, but prevent auto-focus kicking in. I need a specific lens position during capture.

I've made the simplest app I can that turns Flash on using an [AVCapturePhotoSettings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings) object, locks focus on the [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice) using `[device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]` and then takes a picture using [capturePhotoWithSettings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648765-capturephotowithsettings?language=objc).

Regardless of the focus lock, auto focus still often happens, particularly when the preview is out of focus. Am I missing any settings, or a new way to lock focus?

I also tried adding [setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624617-setfocusmodelockedwithlenspositi?language=objc) which moves the lens position correctly, but it is still followed by an autofocus.

Is there an app on the store than can successfully lock focus during a flash photo?

```
// ViewController.h
//#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//
//@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate>
//
//@end

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic) AVCapturePhotoOutput *stillImageOutput;
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *videoPreviewLayer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *preview_view;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *take_picture_btn;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    self.videoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.session];
    self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    self.videoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    [self.preview_view.layer addSublayer:self.videoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:NULL];
    [self.session addInput:deviceInput];

    self.stillImageOutput = [AVCapturePhotoOutput new];
    [self.session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];

    [self.session commitConfiguration];

    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^{
        [self.session startRunning];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.preview_view.bounds;
        });
    });
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.session stopRunning];
}

- (IBAction)take_picture:(id)sender {
    AVCapturePhotoSettings *settings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettings];
    settings.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOn;
    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [self.stillImageOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:settings delegate:self];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output didFinishProcessingPhoto:(AVCapturePhoto *)photo error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSData *imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation;
    if (imageData) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
    }
}

@end
```

UDPATE: I've gone through Apples technical support. They have recognised this as a bug in the API on iPhone 8 and above. The auto-focus is not bypassed correctly when fixing the lens position. As of iOS 12.1.4 this is still an issue, but hopeful for a fix. No work around found as of yet.